# Как записать формулу рекурсивным способом?

Tags: c++

Не могу никак понять как записать формулу(на фото) рекурсивным способом.
[image: Как можно записать эту формулу рекурсивным способом?]

Answer (score 1):

То, что слева, запишите как `x(a,k,n+1)`.

Это формула для вычисления следующей итерации функции x(), значение которой сходится к корню k-й степени ([вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8F_n-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8), k и n там наоборот)

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую)